# How to select a specific <li> with jquery get the attr value of value and display it on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have an assignment that goes as follows:

Create an event listener so when you click any list item the value of its "value" attribute will be displayed next to this line.

I have in my HTML and ordered list with 8 list items. value=1,2,3.. etc
Where im at now

```
$("li").click(function () {

   var value = $("li").attr("value");
   $("#spanFieldId").text(value);

});`
```

spandFieldId is where the list item value should print. At the moment it always print 1 whether i click the first list item, the second or any other.

So basicly, how do i get it to select the specific li (which i click on) with jquery take out the attr value of value and display it on the website? List item in html look like this

```
<li value="3">blablablabla</li>
<li value="4">blablablabla</li>
<li value="5">blablablabla</li>
```

Any suggestions out there?

Comment: Whoever wrote that assignment needs to learn that list items don't have a value attribute. But to answer your question, Google "jQuery $(this)"

Comment: @MaxZoom What are you talking about?

Comment: @j08691 As per current [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)  a `value` attribute is allowed and valid for **<li>** tag.

Comment: @MaxZoom - Yes, but only for ordered lists. And that feature was deprecated in HTML 4 something and reintroduced in 5, but definitely not typical.

Comment: @j08691 I think your interpretation of **<li>** tag documentation is not quite correct, as it states: `The value attribute has no meaning for unordered lists (<ul>) or for menus (<menu>)` but it does not mean the attribute can not be used there.

Comment: @MaxZoom I don't see anything wrong with my interpretation. When used with a `<ul>` the value attribute on a `<li>` is meaningless. Pretty basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
var value = $("li").attr("value");
```

with

```
var value = $(this).attr("value");
```

The string selector `"li"` selects *all* `<li>`s and the `.attr()` will only return the first value found in that selection. Using `this` instead takes advantage of the context that jQuery passes to listeners, which contains a reference to the DOM element the event is acting on.

Comment: Thank you very much :)  great explanation :)

Comment: @JacobJensen if this answers your question, it is customary to select the checkmark below the vote counter for the answer to indicate that it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("li").click(function () {

   var value = $(this).attr("value");
   $("#spanFieldId").text(value);

});
```

Comment: @JacobJensen Glad to help! You might consider accepting another answer as they have more description as to why this code works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var value = $("li").attr("value");
```

use

```
var value = $(this).attr("value");
```

That will select the clicked list instead of the first one.